# Decimal validation without any other character in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs, typescript

I want to write a regex in JS to validate 8 digit number which can have decimals.Currently I have written `/^\d+$/` which accepts any other character such as ( , * $ etc. How should I write this which should accept numbers and dot (.)

For an example, The numbers should like this.

12345
12345.80

No any other character should be allowed.

Comment: Can you add an example or two? Many numbers have decimals :-)

Comment: the examples are not 8 digit?

Comment: This should do it: `/^[\d.]{8}$/` (this will also match `12.34.56` though). And `/^\d+$/` does definitely not match ( or * or $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look for leading decimals, an optional dot and optional digits.

```js
var regex = /^\d+\.?\d*$/;
   
console.log(['12345', '12345.80', '..'].map(RegExp.prototype.test, regex));
```

Comment: I'd maybe go for `/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/` to disallow trailing dots.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, if that is a requirement ...?

Comment: No idea if it's a requirement :)

Answer (score 2):

This should check for number and dots:

```
/^[0-9.]+$/
```

For Europeans who also includes commas:

```
/^[0-9.,]+$/
```

Comment: This would still allow a whole range of values that are not valid decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

"1", "1.2", "2.22", "23412.1254673" are valid formats

"1.", ".01" and any other characters in the string are invalid formats

Explanation:
^ - starts with

\d+ - match one or more digits

.\d+ - one dot, followed by one or more digits

(.\d+)? - decimal part is optional

Hope this helps.